# IntelliJ file tabl colors not changing.(I have already tried older posts here)

Tags: intellij-idea

I tried disabling the scope and under editor->general, the settings do not seem to fix. I can barely see the names of the files that are open. And I am also not able to change the appearance of the active tab.

[image]

And I have the following setting currently
[image]

Also the scope setting, I totally disabled.
[image]

I have spent over 3 hours trying to fix this, so admins, before u mark it as duplicate, do your research that it is not duplicate and some similar questions are more than 8 years old on stackoverflow and new settings are not the same as old ones

Answer (score 0):

Filename colors come from VCS status settings (new, modified, up to date, etc.). You can check the relations in **Settings | Version Control | File Status Colors**.

On the picture below, `Main.java` has been modified, while `Interface.java` is up to date (= no changes since last commit):

[image]

By default, up-to-date files do not have any special file status color assigned to them, so it's just your regular UI font color on the tab.

In the Editor Color Scheme settings for the selected tab, 'Foreground' color option *only works for regular files with no status colors on them*. VCS status color overrides it.

'Background' option works for all files regardless.

[image]

To change the font color of files that have an active VCS status, you can mess with the **Version Control | File Status Colors** settings:

[image]